# Query to retrieve all students in the same classes as one student

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new/bad at SQL and I am having trouble creating a query to solve the problem below. I was wondering what approach I should do to create an appropriate query.

Jack is in classes Chem, Gym, and Math. Find all the students in the same classes as Jack. ID of Class is referred to Student.

Sample data

```
Student
StudentID   Name
1           Jack
2           Brad
3           Tom
4           Vince
5           Tim

Class
StudentID(FK)   class
1               Chem
2               Chem
3               Chem
4               Gym
2               Gym
1               Math
2               Cooking
3               Cooking
```

I got as far as

`SELECT name FROM Student JOIN Class ON (.....)`

Problems like these are a bit daunting to me. I feel as though I should start small and expand to create the following query but this is quite difficult for me. If anyone could recommend resources to help create queries I would be more than happy to look at them. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend renaming the ID field in your class table. One would think it's an ID for the class, but it seems to really be the foreign key for the Student table.

Comment: @KathyA. thank you, i forgot to mention taht in the question

Comment: Also normalize the Class table letting the class types (Chem, Gym, Math etc) become a table of its own. The table Class can then become many to many mapping table with two foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to find all the students who have at least one mutual class with the given student? I'd probably just use some nested queries. I'm sure you could do it with a clever `JOIN`, and I'm sure someone will suggest that if you can, but just from a readability and simplicity standpoint, this would do what you're looking for and it'd be pretty easy to debug if it didn't.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Student]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM [Class]
              WHERE [Class].[StudentID] = [Student].[ID]
                    AND [class] IN (SELECT [class]
                                    FROM [Class]
                                    WHERE StudentID = @masterStudentId))
      AND StudentID <> @masterStudentId
```

The last line just makes sure we don't return the student that you passed in (since clearly he has mutual classes with himself). You may or may not want to remove that, pending your implementation.

**Edit:**

Alright, just for fun, here's a more complicated one with `JOIN`s that I *think* works. I tested it in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ddb56/10/0).

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentB.*
FROM [Student] AS StudentA
INNER JOIN [Class] AS ClassA ON StudentA.StudentID = [ClassA].StudentID
INNER JOIN [Class] AS ClassB ON ClassA.class = [ClassB].class
INNER JOIN [Student] AS StudentB ON StudentB.StudentID = [ClassB].StudentID
WHERE StudentA.StudentID = @masterStudentId
```

Comment: Yep, a few different ways and this should be one of them which work

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to balance the two approaches of `JOIN`'s and Nested queries to enhance readability, here are some options:

Looking at the question, it seems like you already know which classes Jack is in.  If that is the case you could write the following simple one-join query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.Name
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.StudentId = Student.StudentId
WHERE Class.class in ('Chem','Gym','Math')
AND Student.Name <> 'Jack'
```

This will return the names of all students in the classes mentioned.  However, it looks like from your sample table that Jack is actually not listed as being in "Gym" (maybe he's a late registration and has not been updated in the master table yet!), so could this be a trick question?  I'll let you be the judge but the following will return all the students in the same classes as Jack as represented in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student.Name
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.StudentId = Student.StudentId
WHERE Class.class in 
(
    SELECT Class.class FROM Class
    INNER JOIN Student ON Student.StudentId = Class.StudentId
    WHERE Student.Name = 'Jack'
)
AND Student.Name <> 'Jack'
```

The example above simply replaces the "known" classes with a list of Jack's classes as represented by the table.